# How to pass a variable inside a jquery function $.each($("abc")...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to iterate a bunch of SELECT OPTION html drop-down fields and from the ones that are NOT empty, take the values and add a hidden field for a PAYPAL shopping cart.

My problem is that for some reason, the variable "curitem" is not passed inside the `each` function and I can't add the hidden field like they should. All I get is "NaN" or "undefined".

What PAYPAL expects is: item_name_1, item_name_2, etc. All numbers must iterate by +1.

How can I do this?

Thanks a bunch in advance

```
var curitem;

$.each($("select"), function(index, item) {

    var attname = $(this).attr("name");
    var nom = $(this).attr("data-nom");
    var prix = $(this).attr("data-val");
    var partname = attname.substring(0, 1);
    var qte = $(this).val();

    // i want all my <select option> items that the NAME start with "q" AND have a value selected
    if (partname == "q" && isNaN(qte) == false && qte > 0) {

        // item name
        var inp2 = document.createElement("input");
        inp2.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        inp2.setAttribute("id", "item_name_"+curitem);
        inp2.setAttribute("name", "item_name_"+curitem);
        inp2.setAttribute("value", nom);

        // amount
        var inp3 = document.createElement("input");
        inp3.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        inp3.setAttribute("id", "amount_"+curitem);
        inp3.setAttribute("name", "amount_"+curitem);
        inp3.setAttribute("value", prix);

        // qty
        var inp4 = document.createElement("input");
        inp4.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        inp4.setAttribute("id", "quantity_"+curitem);
        inp4.setAttribute("name", "quantity_"+curitem);
        inp4.setAttribute("value", qte);

        // add hidden fields to form
        document.getElementById('payPalForm').appendChild(inp2);
        document.getElementById('payPalForm').appendChild(inp3);
        document.getElementById('payPalForm').appendChild(inp4);


        // item number
        curitem = curitem + 1;
    }
});
```

Comment: why not set `var curitem = 0;` ?

Comment: One more thing: you can access your "data-" tag attributes via $.data() method

Comment: Why not use `index` instead? And `$('select').each(function(index, item) {...})` might be nicer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to initialize curitem variable.

`var curitem = 1;`

Comment: it's initialized in the first line of code. If I put it inside the jquery, it doesnt work.

Comment: The var curitem is undefined in the first line. You need to give it a value inorder for this to work "curitem = curitem + 1;"

Comment: ok... this is weird. At first, `curitem` WAS defined like you told me. Then, when I posted here, I tried just doing `var curitem;`. Then, just playing around, I changed it to `var i = 0;` ... and it WORKED. I wonder if my Macrabbit Espresso software is not creating bugs that I can't 'see'...